# Can I flush Redis without wiping user sessions?

Tags: symfony, redis, doctrine

I recently updated my schema in Symphony 2.7 project with Doctrine, but I was still getting an error. It turned out that I had to run:

```
app/console redis:flushall
```

In order for the schema to update accordingly and not be mapped incorrectly.

Is there a way for me to implement schema changes without having to kill user sessions when I run redis:flushall?

It's very inconvenient when deploying code to a production server to have to kill user sessions.

Thanks for your help!